# SharePoint 2013 - Anonymous Site - Chrome SharePoint Plugin

Tags: sharepoint, iis, sharepoint-2013

When anonymously browsing a SharePoint 2013 site configured for anonymous access I see a warning bar with the following wording:

Chrome for Mac displays:

> Could not load SharePoint Browser Plug-in.

Chrome for Windows displays:

> Microsoft Office needs your permission to run.

What is embedded in the page that makes Chrome want to run a plugin, and how can I remove it?  I can't seem to find anything about this, apologies if it has been answered.

Comment: In the future, I suggest asking questions specific to SharePoint at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com where they will get more visibility from SharePoint specialists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the Name.dll conflict documented in the [SharePoint browser support KB Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx).

To remove this warning, you have two options.

There is a Web Application General Setting called "Person Name Actions and Presence Settings" that you can turn off if you don't need this functionality for any site collection in the web application. [Randy Drisgill's post](http://blog.drisgill.com/2010/02/removing-name-activex-control-warning.html) has a walk through with screen shots in the SharePoint 2010 User Interface which is very similar.

Alternatively, try modifying the master page as [Alex suggests in a SuperUser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/42698/sharepoint-annoyances-what-is-name-dll/43138#43138) on the same subject. Add the JavaScript below to the master page to disable the presence icon if you don't need it. You rarely need it on web site primarily accessed anonymously.

```
function ProcessImn()
{ }
function ProcessImnMarkers()
{ }
```

**See Also**

- [Message in the Information bar in Internet Explorer 7 when you browse
  to a Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 site or to a SharePoint Server
  2007 site: "The Web site wants to run the following add-on: 'Name
  ActiveX Control'"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931509)

Comment: Make sure to put the JavaScript at the bottom of the master page.